# How submit a ticket to request animal activity triggers for Nest Cameras?

Tags: nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

I'm using Home assistant and linked it to Google's SDM (Smart Device Management) to access triggers from my outdoor Nest Cam. It is supporting triggers if person is detected or motion. However what I'm interested in is triggers when animal/activity detected to send a TTS message to my Nest Hub to alert us because we are having an issue with a neighbor's cat pooping in our backyard. That animal detection option is available in Google's Home app but not in the triggers options in the SDM. If I rely motion detection instead, I will get that message played a lot when anything moves in the backyard due to wind.

Anyone know how to request to add this trigger feature to the SDM  or if it has already been requested?

I tried to rely on the motion detection trigger, but I get a lot of un-relevant triggers since I'm mostly interested in being notified through the speakers when an animal is detected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Smart Device Management or Device Access currently does not support triggers for animal detection. As part of the [device access camera trait](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-person) we support capabilities like CameraClipPreview, CameraEventImage, CameraImage, CameraLiveStream, CameraMotion, CameraPerson and CameraSound.

I would recommend opening a feature request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/) and we will put it on our road map for upcoming developments.